# Manejo de Productos con Fecha de Vencimiento en Entradas Y Ventas en la BASE DE DATOS MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola a todos espero que me puedan ayudar u orientarme de como llevar el control de un inventario con productos que tienen fecha de vencimiento.
tengo 4 tablas

```
VENTA   
idVenta
ventaNumero
ventaTotal
ventaFecha
ventaClienteId
ventaEstado
ventaUsuario

DETALLE_VENTA   
idDetalleVenta
detv_VentaNumero
detv_Cantidad
detv_PrecioUnitario
detv_ProductoId

ENTRADA
idEntrada
entNroFactura
entTotal
entFecha
entProveedor

DETALLE_ENTRADA 
detE_NroFactura
detE_Cantidad
detE_PrecioUnitario
detE_ProductoId
estado


 ejemplo
si ingresan 5 gaseosas xxx con fecha de vencimiento 30/07/2021 y se venden 3 ya quedarian 2 en el inventario, 
y se realiza otro pedido e ingresan 6 gaseosas xxx con fecha vencimiento 25/12/2021
tendria 2 gaseosas con fecha 30/07/2021 y 6 gaseosas con fecha 25/12/2021
```

EL INCONVENIENTE QUE TENGO ES QUE NO SE DONDE COLOCAR LA FECHA DE VENCIMIENTO DEL PRODUCTO

E intentado colocar la fecha de vencimiento en DETALLE_ENTRADA para al realizar la venta poder marcar el campo estado a vendido, para así poder realizar un reporte que me muestre los productos próximos a vencer, pero nose como ir marcando el campo estado del producto que esta mas vencido el cual se vendio.

espero me puedan entender

Comment: ¿Este es el problema: *pero nose como ir marcando el campo estado del producto que esta mas vencido el cual se vendio.*? Si ese ese, no se entiende lo que quieres decir. Por cierto, pulsa en [edit] y arregla el título de la pregunta, usando mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esta situación que viene bien en tu caso: [revisar](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/a0e95e31-594c-4b76-be24-d95ae9ebde01/inventario-de-productos-con-fecha-de-vencimiento?forum=sqlserveres)

Comment: hola Jefferson Cuji gracias por responder, anteriormente ya habia revisado ese post pero no aclaro mi duda

Comment: hola @A. Cedano así es esta es prácticamente la pregunta 
 pero no se como ir marcando el campo estado del producto que esta mas vencido el cual se vendió.?

Comment: El modelo que generalmente se utiliza es tener una tabla separada de _lotes_ en donde llevas el control de tu existencia por lote y la fecha de caducidad es un atributo del lote. Cuando compras, incrementas la existencia de los lotes que compraste o creas nuevos lotes, según sea necesario, y cuando vendes, restas la existencia de cada lote. Entonces, la fecha de vencimiento puede ser un atributo de cada detalle de compra y venta.